# Dropdown se borra al recargar

Tags: jquery

Al agregar un producto de una lista a una tabla de venta que esta debajo se borra el contenido del `dropdown`, sin embargo la primera vez aparecen todos los registros correctamente:

Al cargar tengo:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

     listarp();
        --demas codigo
     });
```

Y `listarp();` fuera del cierre del `ready`:

```
   function listarp(){

   accion="listar";
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/promocion/procesopromo.php",
        data: { "accion": accion}, 
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success: function(filtrado){

          $.each(filtrado, function (index, item) {

    $(".promo").append('<option value='+item.monto+'>'+ item.detalle+ '     ' + item.monto+'</option>');
   });

                }
                });

        };
```

Archivo completo:

```
var medidas=[];
var cm;
var pago;
var cliok;
var cli;
var id;
var cani;
var contenido2;
var datos;
var cliente;
var fila2;
var nombre;
var medida;
var precio;
var capacidad;
var producto;
var nombrecli;
var canillas;
var est;
var actual;
var lcanillas;
var opcion;
var opciones;
var contenido;
var select;
var canillas;
var medida;
var fin;
var subtotal=0;
var idproducto;
$(document).ready(function() {
listarc();
listarp();
    $('#resumen').on('click','input', function(evt){
    var idp=$('input:radio[name=seleccionado]:checked').val()
    alerta(idp);
});

 $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/venta/carroventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"listar"},
   dataType:"json",

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(filtrado)
            {
    console.log(filtrado);


      $("#resumen tbody").empty();

          $.each(filtrado, function(i, item) {
          var tot=filtrado[i].total2 - filtrado[i].desc;
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].cantidad + "</td>" +
                     "<td>" + filtrado[i].medida + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].idp + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].total2 + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].desc + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" +  tot+ "</td>" +
                 "<td><input type='radio' id='"+item.id+"' name='seleccionado' value='"+item.id+"'/></td>"+


                    "</tr>";                 
        $(newRow).appendTo("#resumen tbody");

              subtotal=subtotal + parseFloat(tot);  
            $("#total").val(parseFloat(subtotal));
    });
}
}); 

$("#efectivo").keyup(function(){
    var efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();
     var entrego = parseFloat(efectivo);
     vuelto = parseFloat(subtotal) - parseFloat(entrego);

           $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);  
});               

    $("#cc").click(function(){

     codcli = $("#codcli").val();
     if (!$.trim(codcli)){
    alert("ingrese cliente");
}else{
    codcli = $("#codcli").val();
      filtroCliente(codcli);     

 guardarDetalle();


 }

 });

  dameclientes(); 

var getParams = function (url) {
    var params = {};
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    var query = parser.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params;
};
idl= getParams(window.location.href);

$("#codcli").val(idl.id);

$('#canilla1').on('click', 'input[value=Confirmar]', function(){


      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      dameMedida(id);

  $("#canilla1").empty();
var nuevo= '<div class="col-sm-12" > '+

         '<div class="panel panel-danger" font-size:30px; name="canillas" >'+
          '<div class="panel-heading" name="unica">CONFIRME LA VENTA DE      '+producto+'</div>'+
          '<div class="panel-body">CLIENTE:'+nombrecli+'<table class="precios"><tbody>'+
           '<tr>'+

    '<td>'+descripcion+'</td>'+

    '<td >'+precio+'</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6">'+
    '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="CUENTA CORRIENTE" id="cc"/></div>'+

    '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="PAGO EFECTIVO" id="e"/></div></div>';


          $("#canilla1").append(nuevo);     

   $('#canilla1').on('click', '#cc', function(){

      $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"cc","cliente":codcli,"idbarril":nombre,"id":id,"fecha":fecha,"hora":hora,"pago":"n","idcajero":idcajero,"idsesion":idsesion},


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
               window.location.href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index";
            }
            });

   });
     $('#canilla1').on('click', '#e', function(){

      $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"cc","cliente":codcli,"idbarril":nombre,"id":id,"fecha":fecha,"hora":hora,"pago":"s","idcajero":idcajero,"idsesion":idsesion},


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
               window.location.href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index";
            }
            });

}); 
 });

 function listarc(){

    accion="listarcanilla";
     $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/envase/procesoenvase.php",
            data: { "accion": accion}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(filtrado){

                for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {


                    var capacidad = filtrado[i].capacidad;
                    var estado = filtrado[i].estado;

                    var porcentaje = (estado * 100) / capacidad;
                    if (porcentaje>=80){
                        var nuevo= '<div class="col-sm-2"> '+

         '<div class="panel panel-success" font-size:30px; name="canillas" >'+
          '<div class="panel-heading" name="unica">'+filtrado[i].nombre+'</div>'+
  '<div class="panel-body">ESTADO:   '+filtrado[i].estado+'</div></div>';        

          $("#c2").append(nuevo); 
                    }else if (porcentaje>=50){
                          var nuevo= '<div class="col-sm-2"> '+

         '<div class="panel panel-primary" font-size:30px; name="canillas" >'+
          '<div class="panel-heading" name="unica">'+filtrado[i].nombre+'</div>'+
  '<div class="panel-body">ESTADO:  '+filtrado[i].estado+'</div></div>';

          $("#c2").append(nuevo);   

                    }else if (porcentaje>=25){
                            var nuevo= '<div class="col-sm-2"> '+

         '<div class="panel panel-warning" font-size:30px; name="canillas" >'+
          '<div class="panel-heading" name="unica">'+filtrado[i].nombre+'</div>'+
  '<div class="panel-body">ESTADO:  '+filtrado[i].estado+'</div></div>';

          $("#c2").append(nuevo); 
                    }else if (porcentaje<25){
                            var nuevo= '<div class="col-sm-2"> '+

         '<div class="panel panel-danger" font-size:30px; name="canillas" >'+
          '<div class="panel-heading" name="unica">'+filtrado[i].nombre+'</div>'+
  '<div class="panel-body">ESTADO:  '+filtrado[i].estado+'</div></div>';

          $("#c2").append(nuevo); 
                    }

          } 

            }
});
};


var d = new Date();
var fecha =   d.getMonth() + '-'+ d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear();
var hora = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
 $("#fecha").val(fecha);  
medida=damemedidas();
 $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/medida/procesomedida.php",
                data:{"accion":"listar"},
      dataType:"json",

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {

       $.each(data, function (index, item) {


         contenido='<tr><td style="width:100px;"><input type="number" id="'+item.idmedida+'" min="1" name="cant'+item.idmedida+'" class="col-sm-12"  /></td> '+
         '<td style="width:200px;"><label id="'+item.capacidad+'" name="medida'+item.idmedida+'">'+item.descripcion+'</label></td>'+
        '<td style="width:400px;"><select id="'+item.idmedida+'" name="canillas'+item.idmedida+'" class="canillas" style="width:390px;"><option value="1">Seleccione</option>'+
        '<td><label name="'+item.idmedida+'"></label></td>'+

        '<td><label  name="subtotal'+item.idmedida+'" class="subtotal"></label></td>'+
        '<td style="width:100px;"><select id="'+item.idmedida+'" name="promo'+item.idmedida+'" class="promo"><option value="0">Seleccione</option></td>'+
        '<td><label name="total'+item.idmedida+'" class="total"></label></td>'+
        '<td><input type="button" value="Agregar" class="agrega" id="'+item.idmedida+'"/></td> ';

     $(contenido).append('</tr>');

      $(contenido).appendTo("#venta tbody");

});

 $(".agrega").click(function(){
    var idp=$(this).attr("id");
    var cant=$("input[name=cant"+idp+"]").val();
    var prod=$("select[name=canillas"+idp+"]").val();
     var subtotal=$("label[name=subtotal"+idp+"]").text();
    var total=$("label[name=total"+idp+"]").text();
    var precio=$("label[name="+idp+"]").text();
     var medida=$("label[name=medida"+idp+"]").text();
       var desc=$("select[name=promo"+idp+"]").val();
       var capacidad=$("label[name=medida"+idp+"]").attr("id");

var idc =$("select[name=canillas"+idp+"]").children(":selected").attr("id");

  $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/venta/carroventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"agregar","idp":idp,"cant":cant,"prod":prod,"total":fin,"desc":desc, "subtotal":subtotal,"precio":precio,"medida":medida,"idbarril":idc,"capacidad":capacidad},


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
   window.location.href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index";
    }
}); 
});
$("input[value=Agregar]").on("click",function(){
    var idp=$(this).attr("id");

    var subtotal=$("label[name=subtotal"+idp+"]").html();

    if (parseFloat(subtotal)>0){
        var total= parseFloat(subtotal) - parseFloat($(this).val());
         $("label[name=total"+idp+"]").text(total); 
    }else{
        alert("falta cantidad o tipo de cerveza");
    }
    });
$("input[type=number]").on("change",function(){

    idm=$(this).attr("id");

    var cantidad= $("input[name=cant"+idm+"]").val();

            var subtotal=parseFloat(precio) * parseFloat(cantidad);
    $("label[name=subtotal"+idm+"]").text(parseFloat(subtotal));
});
     $(".canillas").click(function(){
            idm=$(this).attr("id");
            idb=$(this).val();

            precio=dameprecio(idm,idb);

            var cantidad= $("input[name=cant"+idm+"]").val();

            var subtotal=parseFloat(precio) * parseFloat(cantidad);

       $("label[name="+idm+"]").text(precio);
       $("label[name=subtotal"+idm+"]").text(parseFloat(subtotal));
          //  $("#precio").text(medida[0].precio);
           });
  canillas=damecanilla();

  } 
                });

$("#codcli").keyup(function(){
  codcli=$(this).val();
if (codcli!=""){
  var fil = cli.filter(function (v){return v.idcliente == codcli;});
  if (fil==0){
    alert("el cliente no existe");
  }else{
  $("#nombre").text(fil[0].nombre);

  } }
 }); 
});

function filtroCanilla(id){

    var filtro = canillas.filter(function (v){return v.idcanilla == id;});
    console.log(filtro);
  if (filtro==0){
    alert("el cliente no existe");
  }else{
    actual=filtro[0].estado;

 }return actual; }

function filtroCliente(cod){

    var filtro = cli.filter(function (v){return v.idcliente == cod;});
  if (filtro==0){
    alert("el cliente no existe");
  }else{
    nombrecli=filtro[0].nombre;

 } }
function dameproducto(idcanilla){
$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/envase/procesoenvase.php",
                data:{"accion":"listartodos"},
     dataType:"json",

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(canillas){
  } });     var filtro =canillas.filter(function (v){return v.idbarril == idcanilla;});


  idproducto=filtro[0].idprod; return idproducto;};
function dameprecio(idm,idb){

    var filtro = medida.filter(function (v){return v.idmedida == idm && v.idprod==idb;});


  precio=filtro[0].precio;

 return precio; }
 function damecap(idm){

    var filtro = medida.filter(function (v){return v.idmedida == idm});


  cap=filtro[0].capacidad;

 return cap; }
 function damecanilla(){
     accion="listarcanilla";
return $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/envase/procesoenvase.php",
            data: { "accion": accion}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(filtrado){
                canillas=filtrado;

                $.each(canillas, function (index, item) {

    $(".canillas").append('<option id='+item.idbarril+' value='+item.idprod+'>'+'N° '+ item.idcanilla+ '     ' + item.nombre+'</option>');
    });
                }
                });
}
function dameclientes(){
       var accion= "cliventa";
 return  $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":accion},

dataType:"json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                cli=data;

 }
});
}
function damemedidas(){
return $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"medidas"},
     dataType:"json",

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(medidas){
                medida=medidas;


 }
});
}
function alerta(idp)
    {
    var mensaje;
    var opcion = confirm("¿Desea eliminar articulo?");
    if (opcion == true) {
        accion="eliminar";

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/venta/carroventa.php",
            data: { "accion":accion,"id":idp}, 


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");

            },

            success: function(data){
        location.reload();

}}).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');


  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});

        mensaje = "Eliminado";
    } else {
        mensaje = "Operacion anulada";
    }

};
function guardarDetalle(){
  var d = new Date();
var fecha =   d.getMonth() + '-'+ d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear();
var hora = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();  

$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "views/modules/venta/carroventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"listar"},
  dataType:"json",

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(detalle)
            {
           console.log(detalle);
$.each(detalle, function (index, item) {

    if (item.medida==='ENVASADO'){

         var idcajero=$("#cajero").val();
  var idsesion=$("#sesion").val();
console.log(item);
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"ccenv","cliente":codcli,"idprod":item.id,"cant":item.cantidad,"precio":item.precio,"fecha":fecha,"hora":hora,"pago":"n","idcajero":idcajero,"idsesion":idsesion},


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
                success:function(data)
            {
            $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/venta/carroventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"vaciar"},


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
            window.location.href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index";
            }
            }); 
            }
            }); 

    }else{
          var idcajero=$("#cajero").val();

  var idsesion=$("#sesion").val();
   var cant=item.cantidad;
var cap=item.capacidad * item.cantidad;
var precio=item.precio;
  var idprod=item.idbarril;
var idproduc=dameproducto(idprod);
var descuento=item.desc;

           $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"cc","cliente":codcli,"idbarril":idprod,"idproducto":idproduc,"cant":cant,"precio":precio,"fecha":fecha,"hora":hora,"pago":"n","idcajero":idcajero,"idsesion":idsesion,"capacidad":cap,"descuento":descuento},


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
            $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/venta/carroventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"vaciar"},


            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
            window.location.href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index";
            }
            }); 
            }
            });
    }
    });

 }
 }); 
        };
        function listarp(){

    accion="listar";
     $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/gestionweb/views/modules/promocion/procesopromo.php",
            data: { "accion": accion}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(filtrado){

              $.each(filtrado, function (index, item) {

    $(".promo").append('<option value='+item.monto+'>'+ item.detalle+ '     ' + item.monto+'</option>');
    });

                    }
                    }); 
            };
```

Osea al agregar el producto se desaparecen las promociones en el `combo`. algún consejo?

Comment: El problema podría ser que append te lo mete después de la etiqueta select, es decir, fuera de la etiqueta. Prueba a usar .appendChild() para que te metas las opciones dentro del select.

Comment: Me dice que appendChild() no es una funcion, de hecho el de canillas funciona perfectamente.Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendChild is not a function

Comment: Lo que observo es que, recargando la pagina, se carga una vez si y una vez no.

Comment: Entonces el problema es que tienes conflicto con las llamadas Ajax. Estarás haciendo dos llamadas Ajax a la vez y cuando una de las dos retorna un resultado, para la ejecución de la otra. Tienes dos opciones, añadir "async: false," al ajax o hacer que la ejecución sea sincrona controlando que primero se ejecute una y después la otra.